# Обработчик событий нажатий на клавиши

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


// Класс окна, в котором размещено игровое поле
class okno extends JFrame
{   
private pole gameP; // Закрытая Переменная класса - игровое поле

// Обработчик событий нажатий на клавиши
private class myKey implements KeyListener  
{
        // Метод, который срабатывает при нажатии
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            // Получение кода нажатой клавиши
            int key_ = e.getKeyCode();                      

            else if ((key_==39)&(key_==16)) // 39 - вправо 16 - шифт
            {
                gameP.y += 30;
                gameP.x += 30;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
}
```

Не получается пустить объект по диагонали при нажатии shift и стрелки вправо, в чем ошибка?

Comment: А как у вас внутри одной и той же переменной могут оказаться одновременно два разных значения?

Comment: Почему прибавление а не вычитание?

Comment: Разницы в данный момент нет, т.к. нужно решить с главным вопросом проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что `keyPressed` обрабатывает только одно нажатие, т.е. `(key_==39)&(key_==16)` всегда ложно, так как оно либо 39, либо 16, либо любой другой код, но не два и более одновременно. Вам необходимо фиксировать нажатые клавиши в структуре.

```
private class myKey implements KeyListener  
{
    private final Set<Integer> activeKeys = new HashSet<Character>();
    private final List<Integer> keyCodes = List.of(16,39);

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        activeKeys.add(e.getKeyCode());
        if (activeKeys.size() > 1 && keyCodes.stream().allMatch(k->set.contains(k))) {
            gameP.y += 30;
            gameP.x += 30;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        activeKeys.remove(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```